# Convert leap year C program to Asm

Tags: assembly

So I want to convert this C language program to Assembly:

```
  void main
  {
    int year;
    printf("Enter the year: ");
    scanf("%d",&year);

     if(year%400 ==0 || (year%100 != 0 && year%4 == 0))
    {
        printf("Year %d is a leap year",year);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Year %d is not a leap year",year);
    }
  }
```

Can you help me figure out how it is mapped in Asm? I tried to convert it using this link: http://assembly.ynh.io/ but I'm having an error: Error: Command failed: /tmp/test683852013.c:2:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token

I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The program isn't syntactically correct.  You (at least) need some `()` after `main`.  Besides that, `main` should return `int`.  Write a correct C program and that translator will work fine.

Comment: Two simple steps:  1) Understand the algorithm.  2) Reimplement the algorithm in assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is pointed out in the comment, your program is not even valid.

It should look like :

```
// Include for printf and scanf
#include <stdio.h>

// Main should return an int
int main()
{
    int year;
    printf("Enter the year: ");
    scanf("%d",&year);

    if(year%400 ==0 || (year%100 != 0 && year%4 == 0))
    {
        printf("Year %d is a leap year",year);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Year %d is not a leap year",year);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now it will work with your link to convert it.

But you can also translate it using your compiler. For example, if you have gcc, you can use this command :

```
gcc -S test_asm.c
```

It will convert it to `test_asm.s`.

*Note :* Sometimes you have to use `gcc -S -masm=intel test_asm.c` but it works for me without the additional option.
My man page about this option says :

```
-masm=dialect
          Output asm instructions using selected dialect.  Supported choices
          are intel or att (the default one).  Darwin does not support intel.
```

But if it didn't work on my mac. You may need it on your platform.

Comment: If the answers worked for you, don't forget to valid the answer. It will mark your problem as resolved.

Comment: bye the way what is gcc?